# What are the default login credentials on fresh install of cacti on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: server, cacti

What I did:

1. Installed Ubuntu server 18.04 in a VM inside ESXi.
2. Enabled the Multiverse repo.
3. Ran `apt update && apt upgrade && apt install cacti`.
4. Visited `http://[ip of vm]/cacti`.
5. Tried to login with **admin/admin** which is the only set of default cacti credentials I've been able to google.

```
"Invalid User Name/Password Please Retype"
```

At no point during the installation was I asked to create any password apart from the password for cacti MySQL DB and thus I assumed the default credentials would work.

Comment: Did you have a read through [Install and Configure Cacti](https://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/unix_configure_cacti.html)? It looks like you need to create the user via mysql.

Comment: @SHawarden yup I read that, but that describes manual installation and the section you pointed out deals with creation of the password for database, if you look at the bottom of the page you linked it actually says "Log in the with a username/password of admin. You will be required to change this password immediately. Make sure to fill in all of the path variables carefully and correctly on the following screen." Cacti is installed properly with the db created as evidenced by visiting http:[vm ip]/cacti/install which says "This installation is already up-to-date. Click here to use Cacti."

Comment: Ok, this is getting ridiculous. So I installed phpMyAdmin to try to look into the cacti mysql db for what the admin credentials are and I hit the very same damn wall - cannot login into fresh clean install of phpMyAdmin. No mention of any password during installation of phpmyadmin via apt, every online source provides default credentials which do not work. And people wonder why linux isn't widespread amongst general layman populace such as myself. Would it really be so hard to include a line with the default login at the end of installing the .deb so you could actually use what you installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with cacti.  Found a posting to try using user 'admin' with the mysql root password.  That worked for me.

Comment: Praise Xenu this worked. I still think this information should be explicitly made visible during installation, but I've no idea where to make such suggestion. Nevertheless, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this, the password can be found in the `/etc/cacti/debian.php` file:

```
$ grep "^\$database_password" /etc/cacti/debian.php
```

Comment: Good answer. Default username is admin even though mysql database_username is cacti in `debian.php`